# How can I make stationary lava with the fluid simulation in blender?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am wondering how to make stationary lava with a fluid simulation in blender.  I don't want it to be an object I want it to be fluid.  And I also don't want it to be filling up as the animation starts.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want.. Do you want it to be completely static? Or just not flowing around very much (perhaps some subtle motion)? (What do you mean by "not an object"?)

Comment: +gandalf3      I want it to be sitting completly still, not            moving at all.  I mean, I want it to be fluid, but sitting still.  Not just an object sitting still.

Comment: You can convert the fluid to an object by applying the fluid modifier (or by pressing `Alt C` *>Mesh*). It won't move, but it will be an object instead of a fluid domain.. Any particular reason why you don't want it to be an object?

Comment: +gandalf3      Because I still want meshes to fall in it and splash.  I didn't think thats how it worked, but if it can be an object and still have other meshes react to it as if it was still fluid, that would be great

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a fluid sim and start simulating some fluid, as the simulation is baking you can progress through the timeline to see each frame as it is created.

Once you get to a frame you like the look of, you can cancel the bake. Under the modifiers properties of the domain object you will find a Fluidsim modifier, by clicking apply you will remove the simulation and leave the domain object permanently shaped as you see it, as a piece of water frozen in time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Easy, under domain settings, set start to let's say 2. That means that the fluid you pour in will have two seconds to settle before the animation starts.